# Vb.net Expression Expected after "&"

Tags: vb.net, expression

I am trying to write text to a file, and have it all except one error.
It says "Expression Expected"

Here's the code:

```
 Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filepath)
            writer.Write("[HealthBarSettings]" & vbNewLine &  _
"MaxHealthTicks = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
"MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerTick = 200" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000" & vbNewLine &  _
 & vbNewLine &  _
"TickAlpha = 200" & vbNewLine &  _
"MicroTickAlpha = 140" & vbNewLine &  _
"MicroTickHeight = 0.5" & vbNewLine &  _
"MegaTickAlpha = 255" & vbNewLine &  _
"TickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine &  _
"MicroTickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine &  _
"MegaTickThickness = 2.0" & vbNewLine &  _
 & vbNewLine &  _
"UseCompression = 1" & vbNewLine &  _
"GoTransparent = 1" & vbNewLine &  _
```

The error is on line 8 were it says "& vbNewLine & _" with nothing else on the line, the first & is underlined. There's no errors on the other lines like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 8 to:

```
"DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000" & vbNewLine  _

 & vbNewLine &  _
```

The problem was the extra &. You don't need a concatenation operator when using _

Answer (score 2):

I really hate string concatenations. Just to avoid it I would write

```
Dim sb = new StringBuilder(680)
sb.AppendLine("[HealthBarSettings]")
sb.AppendLine("MaxHealthTicks = 50")
sb.AppendLine("MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100")
sb.AppendLine("DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50")
sb.AppendLine("DefaultHealthPerTick = 200")
sb.AppendLine("DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000")
sb.AppendLine()
sb.AppendLine("TickAlpha = 200")
sb.AppendLine("MicroTickAlpha = 140")
sb.AppendLine("MicroTickHeight = 0.5")
sb.AppendLine("MegaTickAlpha = 255")
sb.AppendLine("TickThickness = 1.0")
sb.AppendLine("MicroTickThickness = 1.0")
sb.AppendLine("MegaTickThickness = 2.0")
sb.AppendLine()
sb.AppendLine("UseCompression = 1")
sb.AppendLine("GoTransparent = 1")
writer.Write(sb.ToString())
```

I have created a StringBuilder with an initial capacity of 680 chars. (Assuming 17 lines with 40 chars each). The [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) has an internal buffer where it store the characters. This buffer start with a 16 char capacity. You could call the constructor of the StringBuilder saying that you need 1K buffer. This will create the internal buffer for the requested size and, if it is large enough, the framework don't need to do a resizing operation when, adding more characters, you exceed the buffer current size.

Comment: +1 Yep, that's the way to do it. This is efficient as every time a string is concatenated using `&` the original string is left in memory.

Comment: And with a little calc on the final string length it is possible to avoid also the internal resize of the stringbuilder buffer

Comment: StringBuilder has an internal buffer where it store the characters. This buffer start with 16 char size. You could call the constructor of the StringBUilder saying that you need 1K buffer. This will create the internal buffer for the requested size and, if it is large enough, you don't incur in a resizing operation when adding more characters exceed the buffer current size

Answer (score 0):

you have used & sign twice

```
1. "MaxHealthTicks = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
2. "MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100" & vbNewLine &  _
3. "DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
4. "DefaultHealthPerTick = 200" & vbNewLine &  _
6. "DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000" & vbNewLine &  _
7. & vbNewLine &  _
8. "TickAlpha = 200" & vbNewLine &  _
9. "MicroTickAlpha = 140" & vbNewLine &  _
10. "MicroTickHeight = 0.5" & vbNewLine &  _
11. "MegaTickAlpha = 255" & vbNewLine &  _
12. "TickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine &  _
13. "MicroTickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine &  _
14. "MegaTickThickness = 2.0" & vbNewLine &  _
15.  & vbNewLine &  _
16. "UseCompression = 1" & vbNewLine &  _
17. "GoTransparent = 1" & vbNewLine &  _
```

See the last Line i mentioned... line 6 have '&' and 7 also have '&' so it used twice
and also same thing on 14 and 15 no line and no need to use if 17 no line your last line

```
&  _
```